# Using Service Principal Account with Connect-MSolservice

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I need to use Connect-MSolservice to list MFA enabled accounts.
Does Connect-MSolservice support using Service Principal Account for authentication?

Comment: See the screen shot which you were asked for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Shortly *Yes* [It supports](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/connect-msolservice-with-mfa/03d28588-d977-449c-9c77-fca329f88416). But not in all version!

When attempting to use [Connect-MsolService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/connect-msolservice?view=azureadps-1.0) with an [MFA](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-getstarted)-enabled admin account you may receive a legacy authentication prompt instead of modern authentication prompt.

Legacy prompt will fail authentication request as it does not support modern authentication and requires either MFA disabled or application password. This incorrect prompt is due to older version of MSOnline PowerShell module being installed on the machine.

> To fix this issue, you need to ensure you have the latest version
>   installed for MSOnline module

Run below power shell command to install new version, *make sure you are running the powershell as admin*

```
C:\> Install-Module -Name MSOnline
```

See the screen shot below:

[image]

Once the updated module is installed, you will need to close and reopen PowerShell window. With a new PowerShell window open, run the [Connect-MsolService cmdlet](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cloud_solution_architect/2015/05/14/using-a-service-principal-for-azure-powershell-authentication/). This time you will see a new modern authentication prompt that will let you go thorugh MFA authentication process without any issues

> **Note:**  PowerShell 1.0 is not supported for your case, so you do have to uninstall 1.0  before implementing above process

For more information you could have a look on following article

1. [CONNECT-MSOLSERVICE AUTHENTICATION WITH MFA ENABLED](https://msexperttalk.com/connect-msolservice-authentication-failure-with-mfa-enabled/)
2. [Service Principal Authentication](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cloud_solution_architect/2015/05/14/using-a-service-principal-for-azure-powershell-authentication/)
3. [Some MFA example](https://absolute-sharepoint.com/2018/03/connecting-to-all-office-365-services-with-powershell-and-multi-factor-authentication.html)

Comment: Thanks .. do you have a snippet sample on how to connect using the Service Principal? .. I couldn't find any reference that MSolservice supports SP for authentication.

Comment: @GiulioAstori Yeah, The link I have shared have step to step snippet. Please have a look on that. I hope it will help you.

Comment: The original post is about using a Service Principal account. This post on SO suggests that a service principal account will **not** work with Connect-MsolService: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55747310/connecting-with-service-principal-using-connect-msolservice

Comment: i dont see the relevant snippet in the links.. post not relevant imo