# Connecting With Service Principal Using Connect-MSOLservice

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-powershell-v2

I am trying to use a service principal I have created in AzureAD to connect via a PowerShell script. I created the SP successfully, created the key, and also created a self signed cert and associated it with the account. I know how to use Connect-AzureAD but Connect-MSOLservice doesn't seem to allow me to enter the values needed.

I have tried using the standard connection string as you would with Connect-AzureAD but it doesn't seem to take the same input.

`Connect-MsolService -TenantId "xxxx" -ApplicationId "xxxx" -CertificateThumbprint "xxxx"`

I'm hoping someone can show me or point me in the direction of how to use the Connect-MSOLservice command using either the key or cert associated with the Service Principal.

Answer (score 0):

**It's not possible to use service principal to Connect AAD via "Connect-MSOLservice"**

**Why:**

Actually, MSOL Powershell is [Office 365 Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/powershell/connect-to-office-365-powershell). It's designed for managing O365 online services. Therefore, it could only be logged in via Office 365 users.

Hence, you cannot use Connect-MsolService with Guest users and service principals because they're not O365 users.

Comment: That makes sense but how are we supposed to automate Powershell scripts that use MSOL services to run as Scheduled Tasks in environments with MFA enabled?

Comment: I can find examples with how to use a partnercenter CSP connection.. can you just do this against an Azure AD/O365 tenant directly?